# how to get the workspace names from geoserver

Tags: geoserver

i am a student and i am trying to build a web application based on geoserver. I have geoserver installed on my PC and i have already build an html multi-form.

I want when user selects option A, this option to be linked with my A geoserver's workspace, and when user selects option B, to be linked with B workspace.

After the selection a new form appears (i have made it with jquery) and i want whatever selection be made above (main form), my new form to get the layerlist from the selected workspace.

Answer (score 2):

You can query the [REST admin interface](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/rest/api/) to find out about [workspaces](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/rest/api/workspaces.html) (and other information). So assuming you are talking to localhost:

```
 http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/workspaces.json
```

will give you the list of workspaces in JSON format (other formats are available).

There are examples of this (and other queries) in various languages at http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/rest/examples/index.html#rest-examples